# Выполнить действия с данными из двух QSpinBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, qspinbox

Необходимо из двух `QSpinBox` брать значение, перемножать и результат помещать в `QLabel`.

**`ui`** - это ссылка на графическую оболочку. 
Выкладываю то, что налепил. Да значение в `label` нужно менять сразу после изменениях в `spinbox`.

```
...

df1 = ui.spinBox.setValue
df2 = ui.spinBox_2.setValue
sf1 = ui.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(df1)
sf2 = ui.spinBox_2.valueChanged.connect(df2)

ui.label_21.setNum(ui.spinBox.value() * ui.spinBox_2.value())

...
```

Comment: сделай нормальный заголовок для начала

Comment: а чем этот плох?)

Comment: бесполезностью.

Comment: теперь хорошо?)

Comment: теперь хорошо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class ExampleApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label_21 = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)           

        self.spinBox   = QSpinBox(minimum=0, maximum=9999)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.df12)
        self.spinBox_2 = QSpinBox(minimum=0, maximum=9999) 
        self.spinBox_2.valueChanged.connect(self.df12)        

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_21,   0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 0)  
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox_2, 1, 1)        

    def df12(self):
        self.label_21.setNum(self.spinBox.value() * self.spinBox_2.value())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ExampleApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да ваш код работает) но в свой я запихать его не могу)))

Comment: мне вообще не понятен аргумент self при наличии ссылки ui ! при наличии ui self не нужен??

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov   если вам нужна помощь, опубликуйте ваш пример полностью!!!

Comment: спасибо огромное))) разобрался - я часть вашего кода добавил просто в файл с графической оболочкой))) 3 дня голову ломал )) спасибо!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov удачи вам :)